# Wix custom action to unzip a file

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I've a zipped file which contains around 1000+ files. 
I was able to bundle the zip file into msi.

But I would like to know how to unzip that file using any custom action

Comment: If you need the files unzipped to the user-profile, I would do this unzipping during the launch sequence of your application instead - after installation, and once per user. This is OK design and ensures that your unzip operation is as simple as possible - unaffected by MSI's complex impersonation / elevation, sequencing, conditioning, installation mode (silent / interactive) and interference from security software, etc... Unzipping in your MSI is not a good idea, for a lot of such fundamental reasons. Please take our word for it. Unzipping to a per-machine location is not recommended at all.

Comment: The msi itself is already basically a zip anyways. You should avoid doing an unzip as part of the installation. The wix heat tool can harvest large directories like this into a wxs file that can be included in your install. I use this for the help documentation in a product I developed with over 2000 files. You can use this MSBuild target to help with your build http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/target_reference/harvestdirectory.html

Comment: Heat does not work recursively, as far as I know

Answer (score 1):

We had this requirement to unzip a file and place or the sub directories and files inside it at a particular location after installation.

Solution:
1. Create a exe (console app) that will unzip the file and place required files at required location.
2. Ship this exe with installer
3. Make this exe run (with execute sequence) while the application is installs.

This may add overhead, but this works.